# How catch exception using Iteratee.foreach in Future

Tags: future, playframework-2.2, reactivemongo, loops

I'm using Play Framework 2.2 and ReactiveMongo. I'm iterating trough all received entries from ReactiveMongo, and getting some property from single entry. Sometimes it throws Exception of inexistent property, how should I catch it, for now using simple "recover" doesn't work.

```
val cursor:Cursor[JsObject] = // QUERY FOR DATA
val processingData = cursor.enumerate().apply(Iteratee.foreach { doc =>
    (doc \ "property")
}

processingData.map { data =>
    Logger.info(s"$data")
    None
}.recover {
    case e =>
        Logger.error(s"Error during parsing $e")
        None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Iteratee.foreach` always return Unit type, so value `processingData` will not contain data and enumerator apply some Iteratee only attach iteratee to emumerator, but don't run it. I think, this must solve your problem:

```
val cursor:Cursor[JsObject] = // QUERY FOR DATA

val getData = Enumeratee.mapM[JsObject]{doc => 
   Future(doc \ "property") //use future to catch exception here
}

val processingData: Future[scala.List[JsObject]] = cursor.enumerate() &> getData .run Iteratee.getChunks
```